# how to parse the javascript object received in response for a post request and display it in angular page

Tags: javascript, angular

**Below is the service call**

```
this.http.post(this.apiurl, {'user': this.user}, { responseType: 'json' })
      .subscribe((data) => {
         this.myRequests = JSON.stringify(data);
         const requests = JSON.parse(this.myRequests);
         this.Items = requests.filter(function(o) {
          return o.detail;
         }); 
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

**Below is the response received from the service call:**

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ] --> This is the array of object
```

**Below are the array contents:**

```
 0: Object { detail: {'id':'1', 'type': 'service1'} }
 1: Object { detail: {'id':'2', 'type': 'service2'} }
```

**Below is the HTML**

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let each of Items">
    {{each.request_id}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access the `detail.id` property

```
<ul *ngFor="let each of Items">
   {{each.detail.id}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get `id`, use following

```
<ul *ngFor="let each of Items">
   {{each.detail.id}}
</ul>
```

Also, you should you prefer and use more contextual names like `item` in place of `each` as in case of long code and nested `ngFor`, one will loose the context.

For tweaking, [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnRcotjliAHU3RGlOVav?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set: `return o;`

And then access with `{{each.detail.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic version of post method of [HttpClient](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) which allows you to specify the response type of your request.

In your case, the Response format seems to be like:

```
interface Response {
    detail: Detail
}
interface Detail {
    id: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Therefore, you can make your http request in following way:

```
this.http.post<Array<Response>>(
    this.apiurl,
    {'user': this.user}
    // no need to specify responseType, json is default
)
.subscribe(data => {
    // now data is of Response Type
    this.Items = data.filter(item => item.detail);
});
```

[image: Generic HttpClient post method]